# BPEL process deployment time

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I am using Jdeveloper 11.1.1.3 and Oracle SOA 11.1.1.3, and creating BPEL processes. 
Operating system: Windows 2008
RAM: 6 GB

The composite application having 5 BPEL process.

the problem is while deploying the application its taking too much time, average deployment time is more than 10 minutes.

Please suggest me is there any way to reduce the deployment time.
(Except this I do not feel system is running slow ther is any performance issue)

Comment: What is your initial analysis? What statistics have you gathered? Is there enough JVM heap size? Does the problem go away after a restart? Is it better if you remotely deploy the app? Are there any exceptions? What does the WL dashboard display? Did you check the Oracle troubleshooting with your analysis?

Comment: Are you deploying onto the same system.  Does your disk activity increase dramatically.  How many soa processes are running in your domain.  Do you have BAM servers and OSB servers running in the same environment, etc....

Comment: yes I am deploying on localhost, and there are 7 other BPEL process running on the server. but I have tried after undeploying all those processes. BAM server I am not using...still my BPEL process is taking too much time to deploy.(Approx 15 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Alot of people have this problem when they are running the server locally, most people suggest that you don't do this incase you have atleast 8gm of RAM.
Most people however run the server externally to their PC however apart from getting a better PC or installing the server externally giving more memory to jdeveloper might help. The other thing to do is to close the applications you don't need. My guess is you have SOAPUI, Database, Jdeveloper, Server, Internet Browser, Documentation and more open.

To increase memory allowance.

1. Go to [jdevhome]\jdeveloper\ide\bin
2. Open ide.conf
3. And increase the memory to a suitable value : AddVMOption  -Xmx[number of MB]M
4. Restart Jdev